# Samba: allow insecure wide links

Tags: samba

[allow insecure wide links:](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#ALLOWINSECUREWIDELINKS)

> In normal operation the option wide links which allows the server to
>   follow symlinks outside of a share path is automatically disabled when
>   unix extensions are enabled on a Samba server. This is done for
>   security purposes to prevent UNIX clients creating symlinks to areas
>   of the server file system that the administrator does not wish to
>   export.
>
> Setting allow insecure wide links to true disables the link between
>   these two parameters, removing this protection and allowing a site to
>   configure the server to follow symlinks (by setting wide links to
>   "true") **even when unix extensions is turned on**.

According to manual setting `allow insecure wide links = yes` should be enough to allow symlinks outside the shared path however it's not working for me unless I set `unix extensions = no`.

`testparm` is not even showing this variable?!

```
# testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[Public]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
[global]
    workgroup = test
    server string = SambaBox
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/smb.log
    max log size = 50
    smb ports = 139
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
    load printers = No
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = Yes
    show add printer wizard = No
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[Public]
    comment = Public
    path = /data/Public
    valid users = smbguest
    create mask = 0644
    force create mode = 0644
    force directory mode = 0755
    map archive = No
    wide links = Yes
```

Comment: If testparm doesn't show a variable, then it is set to the default value.

Comment: If pointing to the directory proves unworkable, perhaps a bind mount would work (something like `mount -o bind /a_dir /here_also`).

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled wide link support but it does not work, SELINUX is probably blocking you.

Try to issue `setenforce 0` and to retest your configuration. If it works, then you found your problem's source.

If this does not work, in [global] section add:

- wide links = yes
- allow insecure wide links = yes
- unix extensions = no

Than restart samba and re-try your test case.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not SELinux, I've disabled it in order to test this.

Comment: I've edited my answer, give it a look.

Comment: Yes, that works however I don't want to disable `unix extensions` and if I understand manual correctly `allow insecure wide links = yes` should help but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: From my experience I found every second paragraph in the samba man pages to provide unclear or inconsistent information. The only way to achieve what you want is by setting this variables mentioned by @shodanshok.  This is what I did and it works like a charm. Make sure you understand what the 'unix extensions' are how they can help. But honestly speaking they tend to cause issues with permissions. Plus they make no difference to the Windows clients, so why keep it on?